How to create a system extension in Xcode 14.2 - Monterey 12.7.6?
Following the documentation, I'm trying to create a camera extension on macOS Monterey 12.7.6 with Xcode 14.2. It points to somewhere in Xcode new target menu which should contain System Extension > Camera Extension as shown below:

However, I'm unable to find System Extension in the menu. The full menu is displayed below.


Where do I find it or the equivalent to generate the same boilerplate to get started?

You need to create a MacOS app first, and then add a target:

and then you'll see the option:


and should it be embedded in the project I just created? Does the documentation have a version selector somewhere?

Yes, it's a extension, it's always embedded as part of your main app. You can't create a Camera Extension as stand alone functionality
